# In Spring,simpleformcontroller with normal values?

Tags: spring-mvc

How to use normal 'html' form with 'SimpleFormController'in Spring  ?I know ,how to do with the spring taglibs and give me an example,if u know how to do it?ThankYou

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source of a page generated with a jsp and using Springs form tag library you should be able to see the format for the `<form>` and `<input>` HTML tags that the SimpleFormController requires.